# Why did my carrots split in a way that looks like legs?

Tags: diagnosis, roots, root-vegetables, carrots

This is the first year I've grown carrots. What gave them legs?

[image: What gave my carrots legs.]

I have a theory that the seedlings merged together. I don't know if that is just silly or if carrots just naturally grow like this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Carrots often develop forked roots when:

- the soil is stony
- manure is added to the plot shortly before sowing
- the bed is too firm
- the soil is very heavy and has not been dug sufficiently - carrots like light,     well-drained fertile soil

If your soil is stony - and this is what usually causes the problem -, you should have better luck with **a short-rooted variety** such as Amsterdam.

Comment: I think i have 3 of those 4 conditions :)

Answer (score 14):

Anything that impedes the downward growth of the root will do this: stony soil, heavy soil (carrots prefer lighter soils), even damage from pests.